# Independence of singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, random-matrices, singular-values

If $X$ is a matrix valued random variables, are its singular values independent as random variables?

Answer (score 0):

Generally not, but it depends on the distribution of $X$.  Also you should clarify what you mean.  For example, if we take (as is often done) the singular values **sorted in decreasing order**, this ordering would usually make them dependent: if $A$ and $B$ are independent random variables such that $A \ge B$ a.s., then there must be a constant $c$ such that $A \ge c \ge B$ a.s.
On the other hand, if $X$ is diagonal with independent diagonal elements, the singular values $|X_{ii}|$ **listed in order of $i$** are independent.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My matrix-valued random variable X has i.i.d. entries. And I do not mean any ordered way.